# New garage door opener doesn't close on first try

Tags: garage-door-opener

I bought a brand new Chamberlain B2405 to replace my old garage door opener that stopped working.

This new opener will start closing but then stop and re-open, like there was some obstruction, but it does not beep or flash lights. Just goes back up. If I push the door while closing, it goes up and beeps and flashes. If I block the sensor, the same.

If I try a couple more times, eventually the door will fully close. I have tried doing force adjustments on it (which should disable sensors), but the issue happens during force adjustment so it never completes.

It closes and opens fine manually, it runs fairly smoothly along the track.

I can't figure out why this thing only works sometimes. Never has a problem going up.

Comment: Don't know much about them, but have read that the closing distance to the floor can/needs adjustment, so it just touches the floor.  The sensors must be clean and in perfect alignment.  Is it dusty when closing the door?

Comment: Sounds like the drive screw needs to be lubricated. There's too much friction, and the unit thinks there's an obstruction.

Comment: You will get the same effect if the torsion bar or springs are not properly adjusted. This is a Do Not Do It Yourself adjustment.

Comment: How is your phone WiFi reception in the garage, since you are using the MyQ phone app to operate